# Convert a stringified list of variables to a list of stringified variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I need to know how to convert a list of variables wrapped in double quotes into a list of strings, e.g.
To convert

```
"[ROLE_A, ROLE_B]"
```

into

```
["ROLE_A", "ROLE_B"]
```

using Javascript.
Probably some sort of regex expression, or if there are any other javascript methods that would accomplish the task.

Apologies for not posting my attempt to begin with.
Here's what I tried:

```
let stringVariableList = "[ROLE_A, ROLE_B]" 
let roles = stringVariableList.replace(/"/g,"");
let listString =[]
roles.forEach(element => listString.push(element.toString()));
```

This resulted in Uncaught TypeError: roles.forEach is not a function

Answer (score 2):

If the variables adhere to the usual rules for identifier names (Latin letters, digits, underscore), then use this `match`:

```js
let arr = "[ROLE_A, ROLE_B]".match(/\w+/g);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I' guess because the user has not shown the attempt and you are giving an answer, but did not downvorte

Comment: No attempt is no reason to not answer. No attempt is a reason to downvote the question, not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without regex, mutate the first and last element and leave the rest untouched

```js
const arr = "[ROLE_A, ROLE_B, ROLE_C]".split(',')
arr[0] = arr[0].replace('[', '')
arr[arr.length - 1] = arr[arr.length - 1].replace(']', '');

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: One still needs to trim the results/names, or better, one firstly starts with splitting by comma-and-whitespace(s). Thus I consider *trincot*'s approach more elegant due to its simplicity.